# How to set condition for all posts with one label

Tags: blog, static-website, web-services

My blog is total 10 post's, 5 post's with 'job' label and 5 "admit card" label
I set condition for 'job' label

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.post.label == "job"'><!-- for label 'job' --><style>.body {width:1200px;}</style></b:if>
```

That is, whenever there is a post index of the job label, then the style (body width) the change

Comment: I don't think I understand completely, this question is very poorly explained. You want to have a different label styles for some 'job' posts?

Comment: How exactly is this related to WordPress? What is a label?